# Wifi thermostat

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

Can I connect[image] C-wire to the empty terminal(red arrow)

Answer (score 2):

### No, no, no!

That terminal is on the wrong side of the transformer!  It's a *primary tap* used when the furnace is hooked up to a circuit or service that is "two-thirds" of a three-phase system, and has *nothing* to do with your quest for the C wire connection point.

Instead, you want to look at the wires that connect at the *top* of the transformer (helpfully labeled "24VAC" with the upward pointing arrows) in your picture.  One of them will measure 0VAC or thereabouts to the R (red) wire going off to the thermostat (that's where the R wire comes from); the other will measure 24VAC or so to the R wire, so this second wire will be where you want to tap your C wire connection at.

Comment: Your second paragraph is extremely confusing. You make it sound like if the red wire from the transformer is the one going to the thermostat that you hook the C wire there.....when in fact that would be incorrect.